# Create new columns in a data frame based on an existing numeric column, a list of strings as column names and a list of tuples as values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that contains a numeric column and I have a list of tuples and a list of strings. 
The list of tuples represents the values that should be added, where each index in that list corresponds to the numeric column in the data frame. The list of strings represents the names of the to be added columns.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'number':[0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3]})

# a list of keys and a list of tuples
keys = ['foo','bar']
combinations = [('99%',0.9),('99%',0.8),('1%',0.9),('1%',0.8)]
```

Expected output:

```
   number  foo  bar
0       0  99%  0.9
1       0  99%  0.9
2       1  99%  0.8
3       1  99%  0.8
4       2   1%  0.9
5       2   1%  0.9
6       3   1%  0.8
7       3   1%  0.8
```

Comment: or ... `df.join(pd.DataFrame(combinations, columns=keys))`

Comment: I edited my question, because I forgot something. My numeric column contains duplicate numbers, so the solution should take care of this.

Comment: Is there always just 1 duplicate?

Comment: No, there can be more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Original post

To get that output, you can just try

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(combinations, columns = keys)
pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
```

which returns

```
   number   foo   bar
0       0   99%   0.9
1       1   99%   0.8
2       2   1%    0.9
3       3   1%    0.8
```

## Edit

Based on your new requirements, you can use the following

```
df.set_index('number', inplace=True)
df = df.merge(df2, left_index = True, right_index=True)
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'number'})
```

This also works for different duplicates amounts, i.e.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'number':[0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3]})
```

returns

```
   number   foo   bar
0       0   99%   0.9
1       0   99%   0.9
2       1   99%   0.8
3       1   99%   0.8
4       1   99%   0.8
5       2   1%    0.9
6       2   1%    0.9
7       3   1%    0.8
8       3   1%    0.8
9       3   1%    0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension, in a `for` loop, I think it's a pretty fast and straightforward approach:

```
for i in range(len(keys)):
    df[keys[i]] = [x[i] for x in combinations]
```

Output:

```
   number  foo  bar
0       0  99%  0.9
1       1  99%  0.8
2       2   1%  0.9
3       3   1%  0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution using:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame()

for model_number,df_subset in df.groupby('number'):

    for key_idx,key in enumerate(keys):
        df_subset[key] = combinations[model_number][key_idx]

    df_new = df_new.append(df_subset)
```

But this seems pretty 'dirty' for me, there might be better and more efficient solutions?